# Set the envelope's timezone?

Tags: docusignapi

How can I set the timezone used on a docusign envelope?

After the envelope is created, if I view the certificate, it says
**Certificate Of Completion**
Time Zone: (UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US &
Canada)

I'd like to change that to Africa/Johannesburg or GMT+2 etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Timezone information is set at an account level. It cannot be set at an envelope level.

> You can select a time zone setting in your **Application Preferences** menu, under **Regional Settings**.
>
> To define regional settings
>
> - Click Regional Settings.
> - Select the Default Time Zone for the account using the drop-down menu.
> - (Optional) To enforce a standard time zone for all users, clear the Allow users to set their own time zone check box.
> - (Optional) To enable users to define their own time zone, select the Allow users to set their own time zone check box.
> - Click SAVE.

See this [link](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-admin-guide-regional-settings) for more information.
Also see [here](https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/How-do-I-modify-time-zone-settings-for-my-account).